# Loading markers from the database causes their IDs to be reset each time, how can I force them to take on my database IDs?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm having a problem with my database and loading markers in my Maps activity. Right now, I have a database holding MapsMarkers (my own class of marker) and a column called "marker_string_id" which holds the ID of the Google markers, which are generated as following: m0, m1, m2, etc. I use this to delete my MapsMarkers, as I delete by the Google marker id (marker_string_id). This works great until the user decides to create more markers and delete more markers. Each time the application is reloaded, the Google markers' IDs are reset, but the MapsMarker marker_string_id's are not. Ex. You have 3 markers, with ID m0, m1, m2. Delete one and reload the application, now you have 2 markers with ID m0, m1 but their IDs in the database are m1, m2. Deleting them no longer works. How can I make it so that the markers load with the correct ID?

Here is my method in my maps activity for loading the markers:

```
/**
 * Method that adds the actual Google marker to the map in loadmarkers
 * @param lat
 */
private void loadMarkersAdd(LatLng lat) {

        Marker uMarker = Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)) //Blue marker
                .position(lat) //Places marker at hold area
                .snippet(description));
        String acc = uMarker.getId();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "New marker ID is " + acc);

}

/**
 * Method for loading the markers onto the map in onResume, onCreate
 */
private void loadMarkers() {
    try {
        databaseHelper.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Loadmarkers DBOpen failed");
    }

    List<MapsMarker> markersList = databaseHelper.getAllMarkers();
    for(int i = 0; i < markersList.size(); i ++) {
        LatLng lat = new LatLng(markersList.get(i).getLat(), markersList.get(i).getLon());
        String userMarkerIds = markersList.get(i).getId();
            if (userMarkerLatLng.contains(lat) || userMarkerIDs.contains(userMarkerIds)) {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Breaking contains");
                break;
            } else {
                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Adding google maps marker");

                loadMarkersAdd(lat); //Loads google maps markers if the marker isnt already there, prevents multiple google markers from being added
            }
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "LoadMarks looping");
    }
}
```

My method for getting all markers from the database (used when loading markers):

```
/**
 * Returns a list of all markers currently in the database
 *
 * @return
 */
public List<MapsMarker> getAllMarkers() {      //Cursor is basically the "pointer" where the database is looking at on the table at a given moment
    List<MapsMarker> markers = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database opening failed");
    }

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_LOCATION, allMarkerColumns,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned " + cursor.getCount() + " marker table rows");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "GetAllMarkers if statement was run");
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { //while successfully moves to new row in table, return true
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "While loop running");
            MapsMarker marker = new MapsMarker(null, null, null);
            marker.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_MARKER_ID)));
            marker.setLat(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LAT)));
            marker.setLon(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LONGITUDE)));
            markers.add(marker);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Closing getAllMarkers cursor");
    cursor.close(); //frees up cursor
    close();
    return markers;

}
```

And finally, my save and delete methods:

```
/**
 * Method for adding a marker to the database and returning its ID if needed (for deletion, find, etc.)
 * @return
 */
public void saveMapsMarker(MapsMarker marker) {
    open();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Dont .put COLUMN_MARKER_ID because it is autoincrementing
    values.put(COLUMN_MARKER_STRING_ID, marker.getId());
    values.put(COLUMN_LAT, marker.getLat());
    values.put(COLUMN_LONGITUDE, marker.getLon());

    db.insert(TABLE_LOCATION, null, values);
    close();
}

/**
 * Method for deleting marker by ID
 *
 * @param id
 */
public void deleteMapsMarker(String id) {
    open();
    db.delete(TABLE_LOCATION,
            COLUMN_MARKER_STRING_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    close();
}
```

EDIT:
Here are the new methods I've added. It sort of works, but I'm getting the same problem again. Now, when I add a new marker to the map to check its ID against the IDs of the markers in the database, the new marker's ID is reset as well.

```
private void loadMarkers() {
    try {
        MyApplication.getDBHelper().open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Loadmarkers DBOpen failed");
    }
    MapsMarker mapsMarker = new MapsMarker();

    List<MapsMarker> markersList = mapsMarker.getAllMarkers();

    for(int i = 0; i < markersList.size(); i ++) {
        LatLng lat = new LatLng(markersList.get(i).getLat(), markersList.get(i).getLon());

        Marker IdMarker = Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lat)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.building_icon)));

        MapsMarker replaceMapsMarker = new MapsMarker(); //Create new placeholder mapsMarker to check against database ID
        replaceMapsMarker.setId(IdMarker.getId());
        replaceMapsMarker.setLat(IdMarker.getPosition().latitude);
        replaceMapsMarker.setLon(IdMarker.getPosition().longitude);

            if(replaceMapsMarker.getLat() == markersList.get(i).getLat() && replaceMapsMarker.getLon() == markersList.get(i).getLon()) {
                //Query database and update marker_string_id
                String mId = replaceMapsMarker.getId(); //Pull new marker string ID
                MyApplication.getDBHelper().updateMarkerId(markersList.get(i), mId); //Set database MapsMarker to new marker String ID???
            } else { //If marker isnt in database, remove replacement and google maps markers
                IdMarker.remove();
                replaceMapsMarker.delete();
            }
    }
}
```

And my update method

```
/**
 * Update Marker ID
 */
 public void updateMarkerId(MapsMarker marker, String id) {
     open();
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     String markerId = marker.getId();
     values.put(COLUMN_MARKER_STRING_ID, id);
     db.update(TABLE_LOCATION, values, COLUMN_MARKER_STRING_ID + "=" + markerId, null);
     close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. If you don't need to reload map often, and you have only limited number of markers (say less then 500 or so), you can simply update your "`marker_string_id`" by going through a simple forloop on all your markers whenever you detect a reload.
Here's the idea and sudo code:

On map reload:

```
for(marker m: all_existing_markers){
  //search in database by matching lat/lng
  if(m.lat==database_marker.lat&&m.lng==database_marker.lng){
    update database_marker.marker_string_id;
  }
}
```

Note this is just a sudo code, so you have to do a query for each marker in database. Hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try implementing this, I'll let you know how it goes. So if the user will be loading a lot of markers (1,000+) this wouldn't be good to use, since there'll be a lot of load time correct? Or even then would I be able to put it on a background thread to reduce loading time? They likely won't have many markers at all to load though.

Comment: Only one way to find out, haha. I hope it works for you. But again, if you are going to be working with thousands of markers, I don't think it would be a good idea to reload map often to begin with.

Comment: Haha true. I've edited in what I tried. Basically, it works but now the markers have the same ID, since when I add a new marker in to check it's ID against the ones in the Database, the new marker's ID is always reset back to m0.

Comment: I've found out why, its because my update method is updating all rows in the column for marker_string_id. I'll get back to you when I figure out why this is :)

Comment: Last update haha. I got it working, just missed a small thing in my update statement. I tweaked your answer a bit but got it working. Thank you! EDIT: I spoke too soon :P gotta fix some stuff.